# Redirect to login page if login fails from a login block?

Tags: 7, redirection, users

I have a login form block, when a user fail to login to the site I want to redirect him to the user/login page with the usual error message

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by form_alter

```
function MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_login_block':
      $form['#validate'][] = 'my_custom_login_val';
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}


function my_custom_login_val($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = form_get_error($form['name']) . form_get_error($form['pass']);
  if($form != '') {
    $_GET['destination'] = 'user/login';
    drupal_goto('user/login');    
  }
}
```

If you need like after the correct login redirect to a page use [Login Destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination)

Answer (score 1):

Here a slightly different answer using hook_form_alter

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if ($form_id == "user_login_block")
    {
        $form["#validate"][] = "MODULE_validate_login";
    }
}

function MODULE_validate_login($form, &$form_state)
{
    // on successful login, the uid is set in form_state.
    if (empty($form_state["uid"]))
    {
        $_GET["destination"] = "user/login";
        drupal_goto("user/login"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Got this to work in drupal 7, looks like you need to define both

$_GET['destination'] = 'user';

AND

$GLOBALS['destination'] = 'user';

```
$_GET['destination'] = 'user';
$GLOBALS['destination'] = 'user';
drupal_goto('user');
```